# Disc brake clicking noise

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, clicking

I just took my rear tire off of my mountain bike that has hydraulic disc brakes (elixer5). When I put the wheel back on and started pedaling it made a clicking sound.

At first I thought it was the spokes rubbing up against something (that's what it sounded like, some metal sound). I took the tire off again and took a good look at the disc brake pads, I saw a skinny metal "r" shaped thingy leaning out in the slot where the disc would fit.

Is this where the clicking is coming from and if so how do I fix it? Please ask for any more information I couldn't think of for more clarification.

Comment: A picture might help here as I can't see anything R shaped on the Elixir's I have in front of me.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps its part of the spring separators? Have seen those sometimes go wonky with incorrect installation.

Comment: i had this happen the bolts connecting the brakes to the frame were rubbing on the rotor.

Comment: Please post a picture

Comment: Seth - its two years since you asked this question.   Did you fix it?  If so, what did you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metal "R" shaped piece is likely the brake return spring (#7,8 in the image below):

[image]

If it is visible as you describe, you are likely missing a brake pad, and the spring is contacting your rotor.

You will need to find or replace the pad to fix the issue.

Comment: This was it, thank you and sorry for the late reply!